# [MoinMoin Wiki] Show only specific pages in RecentChanges page

Tags: macros, wiki, moinmoin

How can I restrict the *RecentChanges* page in MoinMoin that only specific pages would be listed.
Since I have a huge Wiki site and pages are organized in a hierarchical way, I would like to let *RecentChanges* page show only limited pages according to different hierarchical page paths.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with moin 1.x.

There is even a little reason for it (which might not apply in your case maybe, but applies in the general case):

Wikis live from so-called soft-security: people are seeing changes via RecentChanges and will look at them, reverting any bad changes they see (e.g. spam, malicous edit, stuff gone wrong, people playing around at wrong places, etc.).

If you reduce what they see, soft-security gets degraded as everybody is just looking at his own stuff.